# Filter special characters

Tags: php

I want to check if a string has some special characters and remove them.

How can I add backslash `\` and slash `/` and `~|%*|'`,`#`, `""` to check all special characters

I need something like

```
preg_match('/\\\\/', $string);
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string);
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace and be sure to escape special characters like the dot (.) with a backslash .

You should then have something like:

```
preg_replace('/[%\.&#-]/s', '', $String);
```

Comment: I have tried this:
$v->$v3=(string) preg_replace('/[%\&#-]/', '', $v->Naziv);
Value is= Keyboard Folder for 7\" tablet And I get it like that but I need Keyboard Folder for 7" tablet